# StackOverflowException when invoking the Invoke method of the MakeGenericMethod class

Tags: c#, wcf, reflection, odata

I'm currently developing OData API based on the WCF Data Service Toolkit Library.

My current problem is happened when a Lambda expression has many operators.

From my experiments StackOverflowException is occurred when the expression has more than 356 operators.

The following statement is where the error occurs.

```
return orderByMethod.Invoke(enumerable, new object[] { enumerable, operand.Compile() });
```

And the following code is the whole code.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a Linq2Objects expression to a given <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">A string that indicates the name of the method.</param>
    /// <param name="enumerable">An <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object that will be filtered.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">An <see cref="Expression" /> to be applied to the <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.</param>
    /// <returns>A filtered <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.</returns>
    public static object ExecuteLinq2ObjectsImplementation(string methodName, IEnumerable<object> enumerable, Expression expression)
    {
        var orderByClause = expression as UnaryExpression;
        var operand = null == orderByClause ? expression as LambdaExpression : orderByClause.Operand as LambdaExpression;

        // The following conditional statement is added to avoid the stack overflow exception.
        int operatorNumber = (operand.ToString().Split('"').Length - 1) / 2;

        // The number is evaluated by executing vary queries. It means that dimension members can be selected up to 356 in a dimension.
        const int maximumOperatorNumber = 356;
        if (operatorNumber <= maximumOperatorNumber)
        {

            var whereInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(mi => mi.Name == methodName && mi.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2);

            var currentType = enumerable.GetType();
            var seedElementType = currentType.IsArray ? currentType.GetElementType() : currentType.GetGenericArguments().ElementAt(0);

            var genericArguments = new List<Type> { seedElementType };

            if (whereInfo.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 1)
            {
                genericArguments.Add(operand.Body.Type);
            }

            var orderByMethod = whereInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments.ToArray());
            return orderByMethod.Invoke(enumerable, new object[] { enumerable, operand.Compile() });
        }

        else
        {
            throw new StackOverflowException("The OData query is too long.");
        }
    }
```

Do you have any ideas about that?

Updated...

**Here is my solution for those who may have the same issue.**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a Linq2Objects expression to a given <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="methodName">A string that indicates the name of the method.</param>
    /// <param name="enumerable">An <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object that will be filtered.</param>
    /// <param name="expression">An <see cref="Expression" /> to be applied to the <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.</param>
    /// <returns>A filtered <see cref="IEnumerable" /> object.</returns>
    public static object ExecuteLinq2ObjectsImplementation(string methodName, IEnumerable<object> enumerable, Expression expression)
    {
        var orderByClause = expression as UnaryExpression;
        var operand = null == orderByClause ? expression as LambdaExpression : orderByClause.Operand as LambdaExpression;

        var whereInfo = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(mi => mi.Name == methodName && mi.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GetGenericArguments().Count() == 2);

        var currentType = enumerable.GetType();
        var seedElementType = currentType.IsArray ? currentType.GetElementType() : currentType.GetGenericArguments().ElementAt(0);

        var genericArguments = new List<Type> { seedElementType };

        if (whereInfo.GetGenericArguments().Count() > 1)
        {
            genericArguments.Add(operand.Body.Type);
        }

        // The following conditional statement is added to avoid the stack overflow exception.
        int operatorNumber = (operand.ToString().Split('"').Length - 1) / 2;

        // If the number of selected members in a dimension is equal or less than 356, then the data will be sorted based on the current dimmension with the $orderby query.
        // Otherwise, the method will not perform sorting to avoid StackOverflowException.
        // For your guidance the number is evaluated by executing vary queries.
        const int maximumOperatorNumber = 356;
        if (operatorNumber <= maximumOperatorNumber)
        {
            var orderByMethod = whereInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments.ToArray());
            return orderByMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { enumerable, operand.Compile() });
        }

        else {
            return enumerable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First problem: you appear to be passing a non-null target to a static method. The first argument of `Invoke` should be `null`. I suspect it won't make a difference, but I'd still fix it if I were you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't agree with you. According to the MSDN, it could be null or an instance of the class that defines the constructor.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx

When I changed the first argument as null, it works as well. However, there is the still same error.

Comment: @user2495856 The docs actually say that if you're invoking a static *method* (as you are) then the first parameter is straight-up ignored.

Comment: You're not *calling* a constructor. You're calling a method. MSDN says that the argument is ignored, but at the very least your code is misleading - it *implies* that you're calling the method on `enumerable`, but you're not. You're not calling the method "on" anything, because it's a static method.

Comment: Additionally, we don't know what other operators are involved, which can significantly affect the stack usage.

Comment: @dlev Right. I mentioned when the method is a constructor. However, in my case it will be always ignored. The statement is to sort data.

Comment: @JonSkeet Wow... the order of comments are strange. It's not sorted by time! Anyway, right. I'm calling the method to sort data based on the $orderby query. It's one of OData system query. And I changed the code not to order the data if the number of Lambda expressions is bigger than 356. In that case it only returns data.

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of lambda expressions"? *What* lambda expressions? Are they all part of the ordering, or mostly filtering, etc? It would really help if you could give more context.

Comment: @JonSkeet Here is more information. This is an example of the Lambda Expression: {it => ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((it.ISIC3 == "01_02") OrElse (it.ISIC3 == "01")) OrElse (it.ISIC3 == "011")) OrElse (it.ISIC3 == "0111")) OrElse .......... )} Its length is about 20000. And I think that the number of lambda expression is not the correct name. It must be the number of operators in a lambda expression.

Comment: Okay - I would focus on that fundamentally being a bad way of specifying lots of potential matches. Rather than get a hideous expression to work, I'd concentrate on trying to create a more useful expression to start with, if you possibly can.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you have better ideas?

Comment: Well we don't know where the expression is coming from, so it's kinda hard to help really. Basically you'd need to give a lot more context, which probably isn't appropriate for this question anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well... Anyway, thanks for your help. I think I should change the code where uses stack memory to sort data. FYI, the expression comes from clients and it follows the OData standard query. For example, http://localhost/.../ABC?$filter=(LOCATION eq 'KOR') and (YEA eq '2011' or YEA eq '2012')&$format=json... The expression after '$filter=' will be converted into a Lambda expression and my custom data service provider parses it to generate meaningful data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no any problem in your code. This error occurred related to limited memory.

Please look at given Link:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/stackoverflowexception

Thanks,
HItesh

Comment: I read that article, but thanks for sharing. How can we get over its limitation?